# do we need to write a batchable class to schedule a class

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to generate a report and send a report to email as an attachment in salesforce. I have created a controller, created a class for csv stream and an email template. I want to schedule the class. when I schedule it I am unable to achieve the result. Could anyone help me in achieving this?
The code I tried is created a visualforce component, class, and an email template. 
The code I tried is to schedule it for every 5 minutes. but I am getting an error. 
Do we need to write a batchable class for this

```
global class IncrementReport implements Schedulable {

   global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

   System.debug('Entered Cron trigger');

   rptobj__c r = [SELECT Id, Name, reporttrigger__c FROM rptobj__c WHERE Name = 'ThisReport' LIMIT 1];

   r.reporttrigger__c += 1;

   String s = '0 0 * * * ?' ';

   IncrementReport abc = new IncrementReport();

   system.schedule('Report Job', s, abc);

   System.debug('updating trigger to: ' + r.reporttrigger__c);

   update r;

   }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only write the logic in your scheduler class.

```
global class IncrementReport implements Schedulable {
 global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

        System.debug('Entered Cron trigger');

        rptobj__c r = [SELECT Id, Name, reporttrigger__c FROM rptobj__c WHERE Name = 'ThisReport' LIMIT 1];

        r.reporttrigger__c += 1;


        System.debug('updating trigger to: ' + r.reporttrigger__c);

        update r;

    }
}
```

And then, can run this cron expression from Developer Console.

```
    String sch1 = '0 0 * * * ?';
    IncrementReport ir1 = new IncrementReport();
    system.schedule('Every Hour plus 0 min', sch1, ir1);

    String sch2 = '0 5 * * * ?';
    IncrementReport ir2 = new IncrementReport();
    system.schedule('Every Hour plus 5 min', sch2, ir2);

    String sch3 = '0 10 * * * ?';
    IncrementReport ir3 = new IncrementReport();
    system.schedule('Every Hour plus 10 min', sch3, ir3);

    String sch4 = '0 15 * * * ?';
    IncrementReport ir4 = new IncrementReport();
    system.schedule('Every Hour plus 15 min', sch4, ir4);

    // And so on ir5, ir6 .... ir12
```

As you want to run the scheduler in every 5 minutes, you have to `system.schedule` 12 times as 12*5 = 60 minutes = 1 hour

You can see whether the job is running or not on

> Setup -> Scheduled Jobs